# How to get data from SQL Server and create a treeview in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, recursion, treeview

I have a SQL Server procedure which returns my categories. My `Category` table has a foreign key to itself because my categories have a `Parent_ID` column which are from the same table.

I send these data from SQL Server in this way:

```
SELECT ID, Title, Desciption, Parent_ID
FROM Category
FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('Categories'), ELEMENTS
```

And I get these data in my C# program by:

```
using (XmlReader xml = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader())
{
   xml.Read();
   categories = xml.ReadOuterXml();
}
```

and then pass it to an ASP.NET class which I need to create a treeview with these data.

I need to make the treeview considering `Parent_ID` to make the category and sub-category nodes correctly.

And I think a recursive algorithm should be used.

How should I do it?

Comment: You have posted solution yourself. pass it to an ASP.NET class which I need to create a treeview with these data and then make the treeview considering Parent_ID to make the category and sub-category nodes . What is the problem in doing these steps?

Comment: The problem is how to make a treeview with these information :D

Comment: You need to loop through your xml and create nodes. You don't know how to loop through the xml?

Comment: I can do it with Linq2XML but I have no idea how to create the treeview considering the Parent_IDs. For example I have the category News with ID=1 and the category SportNews with ID=2 and Parent_ID=1. I wanna make the SportNews a child of News in the treeview. I need to check this for all of my categories.

Comment: You can do it like this doc.Descendants("Category").where(x=>x.Attributes("Name").Single().Value == "any value")

Answer (score 0):

Since you've got XML data, I recommend trying an [XmlDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/494y92bs(v=vs.100).aspx).  Since XmlDataSource is a HierarchicalDataSourceControl, your TreeView can use it to populate itself.